# Firebase - Change displayName for Facebook provider

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, react-native

I'm fairly new to the Firebase ecosystem, so I hope I'm not asking something too basic.
I'm using the [firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) along with an e-mail + password registration. When the user signs up using an e-mail I prompt them to select their username and I store it using the `user.updateProfile()` method. This works fine, as the next time I call `firebase.auth().currentUser` I see the displayName property containing the updated value.
As for facebook, I'm using the [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk), and I authenticate the user using the following function:

```
const fbLogin = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    LoginManager
      .logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log('login cancelled');
        } else {
          AccessToken
            .getCurrentAccessToken()
            .then((data) => {
              const credentials = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
              firebase
                .auth().signInWithCredential(credentials)
                .then((res) => resolve(res))
                .catch((err) => reject(err));
            })
        }
      }).catch(err => reject(err));

  });
}
```

Once I store the user's data on Firebase I ask him to choose an username and I update the displayName following the same steps of the e-mail authentication. This seems to work too because if I call `firebase.auth().currentUser` I see the updated displayName. The only problem is when I reload the app the displayName is back to the facebook name. 
My questions are:

- Is it possible to override the displayName provided by Facebook?
- If so, is this the correct approach to do so?

Thanks in advance to anyone that will help :)

Comment: So when you reload the app what code is being called? Why is the facebook name overriding the displayName? I can't tell where this is happening from the code you've posted.

Comment: When I reload the app in the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` callback I see the user returned has the facebook displayName. Actually I don't know why it gets overrided. I was guessing that everytime I authenticate with facebook Firebase overrides it, but when i reload the app I have not performed another authentication, so that should not be the case

Comment: Is the above code called on reload? Or is some other code called?

Comment: The above code gets called when I click on my "Login with Facebook" button. When I reload the app the `onAuthStateChanged` gets automatically triggered

Comment: And are you doing anything in that function like here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged where `if (user)`?

Comment: I have not implemented that part yet. In the callback I'm just `console.log`ing the current user...